# Magento 1.4.1.1 - does it support the cart.create method in the api?

Tags: magento

I cant find any documentation that states the version history, does anyone know whether magento 1.4.1.1 supports cart.create method in the API for programmatic order creation from POS.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  The cart api was introduced in magento version 1.5.  I have added it to my 1.4.1.1 site by downloading 1.5 and copying the following folders;

```
app/code/core/mage/checkout/cart
app/code/core/mage/checkout/api
```

and the following files;

```
app/code/core/mage/checkout/etc/api.xml
app/code/core/mage/checkout/etc/wsdl.xml
app/code/core/mage/checkout/etc/wsi.xml
```

Sorted!

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: ok, it wasnt quite that straight forward, you also need the following files from 1.5; 

And api to app/code/core/mage/sales/model
And quote.php to app/code/core/mage/sales/model
And quote.php to app/code/core/mage/sales/model/entity
And quote.php to app/code/core/mage/sales/model/mysql4